# Determine the specific type of an argument in Racket when the argument's type is a union type

Tags: types, racket, typed-racket

Apologies for the messy title—my technical vocab is lacking, and I was unsure of how to phrase this. How can I identify an argument in Racket as being of a certain type, without knowing either

- the constructors of the type (for use with `match`)
- a function `type?` (such as `integer?`) that checks if it is the specified type?

Specifically, imagine I have some function with the type `(: fn : (All (a b c) (a -> c) (b -> c) (Listof (U a b)) -> Listof c))`; we can imagine it being called as `(fn fa fb xs)`. I would like this function to convert `xs` into a `Listof c`; it should do so by mapping each element `x` of `xs` to `(fa x)` if `x` is of type `a`, and `(fb x)` if `x` is of type `b`. For example, we might take in a list of strings and reals, and map the strings to their lengths, and the reals to the nearest integers.

In the specific case where I know that `a` is `String` and `b` is `Real`, I can write something like

```
(define (fn fa fb xs)
    (map (lambda (x) (if (string? x) (fa x) (fb x))) xs))
```

But this works only if I have a known function `string?` to check the type of `x`.

Is it possible to do what I'm suggesting in Racket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "type of" operation in Typed Racket, so the answer is no. However, you can pass a "decider" to `fn` to select which function should be used to apply for each element.

The [`->` form](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html?q=-%3E#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._-%7E3e%29%29) allows you to specify propositions for [occurrence typing](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/occurrence-typing.html), so you can write this code:

```
#lang typed/racket

(: fn (All (a b c)
           ((U a b) -> Boolean : a)
           (a -> c)
           (b -> c)
           (Listof (U a b))
           ->
           (Listof c)))
(define (fn decider fa fb xs)
  (map (lambda ([x : (U a b)])
         (if (decider x) (fa x) (fb x)))
       xs))
```

Then you can invoke it:

```
(fn string? string-length add1 (list 1 "a" 23 "bc"))

;; '(2 1 24 2)
```

Thanks to Sam Tobin-Hochstadt for his help!